# maven surefire plugin system properties are always null

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have created a maven plugin whose purpose is to bring up an application, which run in pre-integration phase, it sets a system level prop called "LOOKUPGROUPS". I want this property to be available in my integration tests. However everytime i try to get this property it always comes as null.

Also i have noticed in my task manager that whenever my build reaches the integration stage and my integration tests start to execute a new java process comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works by adding properties in MaverSession.getUserProperties.